# php Regex before a character and before another one

Tags: php, regex

I have a list of :

```
firstname.lastname (location)
```

I'd like to extract the firstname, the lastname, and the location. It can be points in the location but it's always between parenthesis.

Can anyone help me please? (and give the explanation of the regex if possible, I dont know why I never can create my own regex...)

I found :

```
#\((.*?)\)# for the location
^[^\.]+ for the firstname
```

But I cant find for the lastname, and I dont know how to match all 3 together

Comment: regexr.com .. go here  and  try your self

Comment: first step google regex, then show us what you've tried https://regex101.com/

Comment: I did, I cant do what I want, I did find for the location, or for the firstname, but not all 3 together, or the lastname

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without regex:

```
$string = 'firstname.lastname (location)';
//you get there array of name and surname
$exploded = explode('.',substr($string, 0, strpos($string, ' ')));

$name = $exploded[0];
$surname = $exploded[1];
//You get there location
$location = rtrim(explode(' (', $string)[1], ')');
```

Comment: Thank you, I dont know why I want to do it with regex, found something on google when I tried for the location and seemed logical to continue with regex for the names.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex for that. [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) on `.` with a limit of 2. Then [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) first parenthesis `(` and  let [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

That's not too difficult with a regex. However, your confusion might stem from the fact that several of the characters in that example string are have special meanings in RegEx.

```
<?php
    $string = "firstname.lastname (location)";

    if(preg_match('/^(\w+)\.(\w+)\s*\((\w*)\)$/', $string, $aCapture)){

    /*Let's break down that regex

     ^       Start of string
     (\w+)   Capture a string of continuous characters
     \.      a period
     (\w+)   Capture a string of continuous characters
     \s      Zero or more whitespace
     \(      An opening bracket
     (\w+)   Capture a string of continuous characters
     \)      An closing bracket
     $       The end of the string

     */

        $aCapture contains your captures; starting at position 1, because 0 will contain the entire string
        $sFirstName = $aCapture[1];
        $sLastName = $aCapture[2];
        $sLocation = $aCapture[3];

        print "$sFirstName, $sLastName, $sLocation";
    }

?>
```

Comment: You should change `\s*` to `\s+` else it wouldn't make sense.

Comment: OP has not mentioned if the space is enforced or no, so I didn't enforce it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's a really good start, but it doesn't work if there are points in the location, or space in the names, I'll try to figure out

Comment: Change `\w+` to `.+?`

Comment: Thanks a lot for that Toto :)

Answer (score 0):

Using a formatted string:

```
$str = 'jacques.cheminade (espace)';
$result = sscanf($str, '%[^.].%[^ ] (%[^)])');
```

Note that if the syntax seems similar to the one used in regex, tokens `[^...]` don't use quantifiers as they describe parts of the string and not single characters.